# reading pdf file custom document properties using powershell script

Tags: powershell, pdf, properties

I am trying to read pdf file custom properties using windows powershell. I found a script which will read custom properties of word file. I am looking for similar code to read pdf custom properties. Any help is highly appreciated on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the iTextSharp library for .NET should be a good starting point:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/